Is there any CTkTreeview in CustomTkinter?
CustomTkinter is a modern GUI that fits my project in my upcoming contest. But there's only one thing. I don't see any Treeview here. Anyone help? I already saw #524 but I don't know how to put the light/dark callback (AppearanceModeTracker.add(callback)) and use it with scale:
  File "g:\My Drive\TinEdu\v0.2-0304-beta\main.py", line 21, in __init__
    text_font = self._apply_appearance_mode(ThemeManager.theme["CTkLabel"]["font"])
                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'font'

Anyone help? Please be quick because the contest is due in 2-3 weeks.
https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues/2357

register a callback for the appearance mode change: AppearanceModeTracker.add(callback)
change font ui scaling: text_font = self._apply_appearance_mode(ThemeManager.theme["CTkLabel"]["font"])

